# Why doesn't a left-floated element go all the way up in the presence of right-floated elements?

Tags: css

The HTML looks like this:

```
<article>
    <h1>header</h1>
    <p>body</p>
    <footer>footer</footer>
</article>
<aside>
    <ol>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
    </ol>
</aside>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
h1 {
    background: red;
}
p, footer {
    background: green;
    float: right;
    width: 70%;
}
aside {
    background: blue;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}
```

See it live: http://jsfiddle.net/GD9Fh/

Why doesn't the blue block (left-floated) float up to the same level as the green blocks (right floated)?

Comment: Seems to be the order I think you might have to float left before you float right. http://jsfiddle.net/GD9Fh/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine a border around the h1, p and footer... the aside can't just "be" inside of that... it's the way the markup is written. You have the CSS idea correct. Check out [this FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/f7bQ7/)

Without understanding what you are *really* trying to achieve, I hope you might find something in here to help.

### solution 01

The article element (basically a div with some semantic meaning) is 100% width by default as all block-level elements are. So, remove the width on it's children and put it on the `<article>`

#### HTML

```
<article>
    <h1>header</h1>
    <p>body</p>
    <footer>footer</footer>
</article>
<aside>
    <ol>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
    </ol>
</aside>
```

### CSS

```
h1 {
    background: red;
}

article {
    float: right;
    width: 70%;
}

p, footer {
    background: green;
}

aside {
    background: blue;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}
```

### solution 02

Rethink the html

Comment: 2014, eh? So you'll finally be a teenager?

Comment: Why would you work so hard to fix markup with css instead of just rewriting the markup properly? And if for some reason, the OP can't touch the markup - and this is what they are stuck with, then the real answer is they need to start looking for another job, because that sucks.

Comment: I'm trying to answer the question - not just put a bandaid on it for points.

Comment: Thanks @sheriffderek. But if that border exists, why is it that the blue block does float up one element (it's at the same level as the footer), but not two elements?

Also, if I remove the `float: left` from the blue block, it does go up all the way: http://jsfiddle.net/GD9Fh/4/. Why is that?

Comment: From what I understand, the original implementation of float() was for floating an image in a block of text. So what is happening is it's leaving the static default flow and allowing the text to "float" around it. - So, when you float one thing... it's a lot different then floating all of the things. I like to float almost all major blocks.Then I treat it like a whacky upside down gravity that sucks things to the top left. At the end of the day - it's not really doing what it appears to be doing.

Comment: put a different color border on each element. remove the background colors. place a padding on the article of .5em --- you will see that the h1 is a `display: block;` by default. The footer and p are given a width of auto when they are floated... and the aside is doing whatever it's doing -

Comment: (there is no floating up or down - only around)

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/GD9Fh/2/)

The `<p>` tag automatically adds a new paragraph markup. Try using all DIVs instead. Also, set the header to a specific height and use absolute positioning for the `aside` and `body`.

**HTML**

```
<article>
    <h1>header</h1>
    <div id="main">body</div>
    <footer>footer</footer>
</article>
<aside>
    <ol>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
    </ol>
</aside>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    border:0;
    font-size:100%;
    font:inherit;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display:block
}
body {
    line-height:1
}
ol, ul {
    list-style:none
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes:none
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
    content:none
}
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0
}
h1 {
    background: red;
}
#main {
    background: green;
    float: right;
    width: 70%;
}
aside {
    background: blue;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
footer {background: yellow; position:absolute;bottom:0;width:100%;)
```

Comment: You could totally do it this way, but you shouldn't. It's going to be 2014 in one month.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your `<p>` and `<footer>` in a `<div>` and float that, it'll do what you're after. To grok why, add another `<p>` to your example, and you'll see that everything is still floating to the left of the `<footer>`.

Answer (score 0):

According to w3schools "Elements are floated horizontally, this means that an element can only be floated left or right, not up or down."

A css `float:right` will have the browser move the element as far right as possible from where it would have been rendered otherwise.

If you need the your `<aside>` to be floated up, place it before the `<article>` element

like so :- http://codepen.io/mrmoje/full/obrBI